# Grep file contents EXCEPT match case WITH context

Tags: shell, grep, cat

I have a file test.txt, with contents like theese:

```
line random text 1
line random text 2
line random text 3
line particular exception 
line except detail 1
line except detail 2
line except detail 3
....
line random text 14
line random text 15
line random text 16
line particular exception 
line except detail 1
line except detail 2
line except detail 3
.....
```

I want to output (for further grep) the file contents filtering where "particular exception" appears, and filtering the "particular exception" details that appear AFTER it (allways 3 lines).

The logical command i thought of is this:

```
cat test.txt | grep -v -A 3 "particular exception"
```

But it doesn't work as i expected.

What is the correct way of doing this?

For some context, what i'm trying to do is to find exceptions in a log file EXCEPT a particular one that is constantly repeating itself, so first i want to clear it.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `grep`, you can use GNU `sed`:

```
sed -e '/particular exception/,+3d' test.txt
```

This finds lines that match `particular exception` and deletes them and the three lines after them.

Comment: I wasn't aware of sed. It worked very well, thank you. I'll mark as correct answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk -v n=3 -v p='particular exception' 'match($0,p) { skip=n+1 } --skip < 0' test.txt
line random text 1
line random text 2
line random text 3
....
line random text 14
line random text 15
line random text 16
.....
```

The number of lines of trailing context to skip is given on the command line with e.g. `-v n=3` and the regular expression to match is also given on the command line as `-v p='expression'`.

The variable `skip` will be decreased by one for every line read, and the script will print the current line whenever the variable `skip` is less than zero.  When the pattern of interest is found, the `skip` variable gets the value of `n + 1` which means that the current line and `n` more lines will be skipped.

`match($0,p)` could also be written `$0 ~ p`.